# Delay in ContinueWith not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

My question is why the delay method is not working (whole operation is not waiting for 4 sec) and 60% is not showing inside the lable1.

To be more precise the sequence of the operations should be like this and whole operation should take 8 seconds.but it takes 4 seconds, just `Thread.Sleep(4000)` inside `LongTimeMethod1()` is working

```
LongTimeMethod1()//delay for 4 sec,show 60%
delay()//delay for 4 sec 
LongTimeMethod()//40% imidiatly
```

**I know I can write code just with await and async but I want to know what am I doing wrong in this code.**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CallBigMethod();
        label1.Text =@"Waiting ...";
    }
    private async void CallBigMethod()
    {
        var result = await BigMethod();
        label1.Text = result; 


    }
    private Task<string> BigMethod()
    {
        return Task.Factory
         .StartNew(() => LongTimeMethod1())
         .ContinueWith((pre) => Delay())
         .ContinueWith((pre) => LongTimeMethod());
    }     
    private string LongTimeMethod()
    {

        return  "40%...";
    }
    public async Task Delay()
    {

        await Task.Delay(4000);

    }
    private string LongTimeMethod1()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        return "60%...";
    }
```

Comment: @PetSerAl it just solve the time problem but it's not address the  showing 60% problem

Answer (score 8):

The `Task` returned by `.ContinueWith((pre) => Delay())` is actually a `Task<Task>`.  That continuation will be finished as soon as it finishes *starting* the delay, but since the delay is asynchronous, it doesn't wait for it to finish.  You need to unwrap the `Task<Task>` so that you're adding a continuation to the inner task and have your program continue on when the delay finishes, rather than when it finishes being *started*.

Fortunately there's an `Unwrap` method that just does all of this for us.

```
private Task<string> BigMethod()
{
    return Task.Factory
     .StartNew(() => LongTimeMethod1())
     .ContinueWith((pre) => Delay())
     .Unwrap()
     .ContinueWith((pre) => LongTimeMethod());
}
```

That said, the whole thing is much simpler when the method is `async`, rather than using `ContinueWith`:

```
private Task<string> BigMethod()
{
    await Task.Run(() => LongTimeMethod1());
    await Delay();
    return await Task.Run(() => LongTimeMethod());
}
```

Comment: thanks for code,it tackle the time problem,it takes 8 sec but still not showing 60% in label

Comment: @E_N_Y That's because `LongTimeMethod` returns 40%, not 60%.  If you switch the positions of `LongTimeMethod` and `LongTimeMethod1` then the results will change.  If you used more meaningful (or at least distinguishable) names for these methods then this would likely be less confusing.

Comment: so you mean there is no way I can show 60% then 4 sec delay then print 40% with this code?!and I know if I change the methods I can result would be different:)

Comment: @E_N_Y Not the way you have it structured.  You can structure your code differently to do that.  At that point you're ceasing to just compute a result.  If you're trying to update the UI with the current progress of an operation then you should be using the `Progress` class to do that.  Have the result returned from the `Task` be the result of the operation, not its progress.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private Task<string> BigMethod()
    {

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongTimeMethod1()).ContinueWith(async (pre) => await Delay()).ContinueWith((pre) => LongTimeMethod());
    }
```

Comment: There is no reason at all to use an `async` lambda in the `ContinueWith`.  It's accomplishing nothing.  This is identical to the OP's code.